# Can't get working 16x2 Character LCD with Pic16f877a

Tags: pic, microchip, lcd, mplab

i have been recently learning microcontroller and now I am trying to make an LCD program with MPLAB X ide and XC8 but in the hard way using no libraries of XC8 but it is not working at all here are all the details:

1. Components:

   - LCD LM016L
   - Microcontroller pic16f877a
2. Pin connections:

   - Register select pin --> pin E0, Read/Write pin --> pin E1, Register Select pin --> pin E2
   - Data lines (8 bits mode) port D.

Now this is the whole code:

```c
#include "config.h"

//port E pin 0 --> RS, pin 1 --> R/W, pin 2 --> En
#define RS TRISE0
#define RW TRISE1
#define EN TRISE2


void blinkEnable(void);
void check_if_busy(void);
void send_a_command(int command);
void send_a_character(int character);


void main(){
    
    blinkEnable();
    __delay_ms(10);
    check_if_busy();
    __delay_ms(10);
    send_a_command(0x01);
    __delay_ms(10);
    send_a_character(0x46);
    
    while(1){
    }
    
}

void blinkEnable(){
    
    TRISEbits.EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(10);
    TRISEbits.EN = 0;
    __delay_ms(10);
    
    
}
void check_if_busy(){
    
    TRISEbits.RS = 0;
    TRISEbits.RW = 1;
    TRISDbits.TRISD7 = 1;
    while(PORTDbits.RD7 == 1){
        
        
    }
    
}
void send_a_command(int command){
    TRISEbits.RW = 0;
    TRISEbits.RS = 0;
    
    PORTD = command;
    
}
void send_a_character(int character){
    TRISEbits.RW = 0;
    TRISEbits.RS = 1;
    
    PORTD = character;
    
}
```

Comment: Each time you write a command, you must send an EN signal. Important to know, which type of LCD are you using? Plus there is an initialization sequence you MUST follow up for the internal's register of the LCD to be set properly. Datasheet here http://www.azdisplays.com/PDF/acm2004f.pdf